# How to find the Chef environment in a recipe?

Tags: chef

I want to run a cookbook_file resource only if the current environment is "dev". How can this be expressed?

The documentation suggests this:

> In a recipe, a code block like this would be useful:
>
> ```
> qa_nodes = search(:node,"chef_environment:QA")      
> qa_nodes.each do |qa_node|                          
>     # Do useful specific to qa nodes only
> end
> ```

But I'm not sure that's what I want - the fact it's a loop seems wrong.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Look in the chef_environment Ruby attribute (not a regular Chef attribute) on the node:

```
if node.chef_environment == "dev"
  # stuff
end
```

Comment: Specifically, chef_environment is a method on the Chef::Node object that returns the value of the node's environment. It is not a node attribute and should not be confused as such.

Comment: Thanks @jtimberman.  I had always thought of an environment being an attribute of a node but it does make sense that it's not.

Comment: Great, this works. So the answer to my original question is to add `only_if { node.chef_environment == "dev" }`. Confirmed.

Comment: Couldn't get this answer to work.  This syntax does work for me:  `if "#{node.chef_environment}" == "dev"`

Answer (score 2):

another elegant way:

```
if ['production','development'].include? node.chef_environment
    #do something here
end
```